# What is the late BF109's (G models) internal fuel capacity?

Tags: fuel, fighter

What is the late BF109's (G models) internal fuel capacity? I've been trying to google the answer for a few hours with no luck, perhaps someone here has the right source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The BF109G could carry 400 liters of fuel internally, and up to two 300 liter drop tanks externally.](http://www.wardrawings.be/WW2/Files/2-Airplanes/Axis/1-Germany/01-Fighters/Me-Bf109/Data/Bf-109G-6.htm)

You can also find the information [in the flight manual](http://109lair.hobbyvista.com/techref/manuals/bf109g3.pdf), but you have to be able to read German. It's on page 7, under "Kraftstoffanlage".